# How to use static and dynamic text inside a Button

Tags: java, android, android-layout, button, dynamic

I'm currently trying to create a cash register application. The user can press buttons to add products to their receipt.

The buttons should have a static text inside that tells users what the product is and how much it costs.

The button should also have a dynamic text called amount: 0x. That when pressed iterates + 1 so it shows amount: 1x.

How do I go about this? I'm pretty new to android so how can I have 1 button with one part static and 1 part dynamic text?

**EDIT:**

Thanks for all your answers so far but i'm not looking for a way to iterate the amount. By using setText I also overwrite the product and the cost of the product.

So I want a way to only update the amount when a button is pressed. Instead of using:

```
button.settext("Pepsi:   1,50" + amount + "x");
```

Is there a way or should I just use setText?

Comment: Do you have a listener on the button? Change the text of the button with setText() inside the listener.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int counter = 0;
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{

    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        counter++;
        button.setText("Amount" + counter + "x"); 
    }
});
```

set a counter, listen for the click event for the button. Now inside click event increment the counter and set the new text to the button.

Comment: ); (not emoticon) missing at the end